# Proguard injar dependencies

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

I'm trying to use proguard for my library project which produces several jars which all have a dependency on one core jar. I only want to shrink the core jar but I need to let proguard know of the references to the core jar from the other jars.

If I give proguard all of the jars via the "-injars" option and then specify a directory for the outjars, will it realize that the other jars reference the core jar? Or does it just look at the jars one by one individually?